# (Javascript) How to find unique values from an array and put them into another using booleans?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, boolean

So let's say I have my first array (arrayOne) with the values of [1,2,3,3,4,2]. I need to compare this array to another array to check for duplicate values (arrayTwo), then display these values.

So, the final output would be: 1, 2, 3, 4.

The catch is I can only use really basic methods, pretty much just booleans, multiple functions, and loops.

How might I go about this? Searching the internet brings up code similar to this:

```
for (a = 0; a < array1.length; a += 1) {
    for (b = 0; b < array2.length; b += 1) {
        if (array1[a] !== array2[b])
            array2 = array1
        }
    }
}

output = array2
```

... so on so forth, but this doesn't seem to work for me (note my code is not exactly like this, but after searching, this seems to be close to what I am looking for).

Any advice?

Comment: You did not show us what the `array2` looks like.

Comment: `array2 = array1` this will reassign the value of the ENTIRE ARRAY. Are you sure you don't want to just change one value?

Comment: Might want to check this duplicate - also has an elegant solution using filter https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229932/184481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner loop check if the current item is equal to an item in the array. If it is, `break` the inner loop. Check in the outer loop if `b === array2.length`. In this case equality means that the loop ended without break, which means - not a duplicate. In this case, push the current item to `array2`.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2];
var array2 = [];
var a,b;

for (a = 0; a < array1.length; a += 1) {
  for (b = 0; b < array2.length; b += 1) {
    if (array1[a] === array2[b]) break;
  }
  
  if(b === array2.length) array2.push(array1[a]);
}

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but I think you want to return the initial array without having duplicate values.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2];

function removeDuplicates(input) {
  let result = [];
  
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let currentValue = input[i];
    
    if (result.indexOf(currentValue) == -1) {
      result.push(currentValue);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(removeDuplicates(array));
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array) you can find more implementations.